# how to get around UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python

I just started programming and tried to write something but (of course) it failed. After I while I got to the real problem: The `UnboundLocalError`. So to save you from all the rubble around I stripped the code down to this:

```
def test():
    try:
        i1 = int(i1)
        i2 = int(i2)
    except ValueError:
        print "you failed in typing a number"

def input(): 
    i1 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
    i2 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
```

Then I wrote down:

```
>>>input()
please insert a number
> 3
please insert a number
> 2 
>>>test()
```

And then I got:

```
that was not a number
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in test
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i1' referenced before assignment
```

How can I solve this in a Pythonic way? Or should I take a whole different way?

Comment: Think about it this way: Regular variables such as `i1` and `i2` are local to the function and not visible outside it.  Your function `input` creates local variables that are unknown to `test`.  If you want to access data in `test`, that data must be global (see the `global` keyword for global variables) or explicitely given to it using function arguments (see Cédrick Julien's answer).  As a rule of thumb, global variables should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most standard way to do this is to give parameters to your test method :

```
def test(i1, i2):
    try:
        i1 = int(i1)
        i2 = int(i2)
    except ValueError:
        print "you failed in typing a number"

def input(): 
    i1 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
    i2 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
    test(i1, i2)   # here we call directly test() with entered "numbers"
```

If you really want to test on the interactive prompt, you can do (as suggested in @FerdinandBeyer comment) :

```
def test(i1, i2):
    try:
        i1 = int(i1)
        i2 = int(i2)
    except ValueError:
        print "you failed in typing a number"
    return i1, i2
    
def input(): 
    i1 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
    i2 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
    return i1, i2
```

And then, on prompt :

```
>>>var1, var2 = input()
please insert a number
> 3
please insert a number
> 2 
>>>test(var1, var2)
```

Comment: +1. `input` should return the variables, so that the OP can test his functions in the interactive prompt: `i1, i2 = input(); test(i1, i2)`.

Answer (score 0):

use the keyword "global".

```
def test():
    global i1
    global i2
    try:
        i1 = int(i1)
        i2 = int(i2)
    except ValueError:
        print "you failed in typing a number"

def input(): 
    global i1
    global i2
    i1 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
    i2 = raw_input('please type a number \n >')
```

This causes i1 and i2 to be seen as global variables (accessible over the whole of the program) rather than local variables (only accessible **within** the function they are defined in - this caused the exception)